# Draw Insertion Point in NSView/NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Insertion point is known as `Caret` in Win32. On Windows, you can draw the caret on the window using `CreateCaret` and `ShowCaret`.

I just want to know how to draw the insertion point on a NSWindow or NSView. So far I found `-drawInsertionPointInRect:::` in `NSTextView` and it is also mentioned that it should not be invoked directly. Do I need to create an invisible textbox and then display the cursor?

Or can I display on NSView/NSWindow?

Comment: You don't call it, you subclass and override it.

Comment: @CodaFi; That is why it is said do not invoke directly. Thanks. But how to display insertion point directly on NSView/NSWindow?

Comment: You can't without faking it.  Just subclass NSTextView and add it as a subview.